# Serialize ManyToMany field drf haystack

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm trying to serialise a field that contains a many to many relationship with another model.
I use drf-haystack to serialize the results by haystack (elasticsearch).

Normally, I would include a m2mfield serializer for the m2mfield in the modelsearchserializer, but somehow when I rebuild the index afterwards, the serialization gives an error saying it is unable to serialise.

This m2mfield does not have to be searchable.

Indexed Model:

```
class ModelIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title', boost=2.5)
    model_id = indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='id')
    m2mfield = indexes.MultiValueField()
    date = indexes.DateField(model_attr='date')
    site_id = indexes.IntegerField()

    def get_model(self):
        return Model

    def prepare_m2mfield(self, obj):
        return [m2mfield for m2mfield in obj.m2mfield.all()]

    def prepare_site_id(self, obj):
        return obj.site.id

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        # Used when the entire index for model is updated.
        return self.get_model().objects.all().filter(date__lte=datetime.datetime.now()).prefetch_related('m2mfield')
```

Serializer:

```
class ModelSearchSerializer(HaystackSerializer):
    /* Tried including a serializer for m2mfield here, but didnt work */ 
    class Meta:
        index_classes = [ModelIndex]
        fields = ['title', 'text', 'date', 'm2mfield', 'model_id']
```

Error message:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.SerializationError: ({'id': 'testdata.model.3', 'django_ct': 'testdata.model', 'django_id': '3', 'text': 'nog 1\n&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;fewfewefwfe&lt;/p&gt;\n', 'title': 'nog 1', 'model_id': 3, 'm2mfields': [<M2mfield: homepage>], 'date': '2019-04-24T00:00:00', 'site_id': 31}, TypeError("Unable to serialize <M2mfield: homepage> (type: <class 'main.models.M2mfield'>)"))
```

I get this error message when Im trying to rebuild the index

Comment: Can you please provide the stack trace as well?

Comment: @decibyte I added the error message

Answer (score 0):

The error message is right: You're trying to serialize the complex values of `M2mfield` instances, which is not possible. In `prepare_m2mfield()`, you should return a simple, serializable value. In your case, probably a `list` of `dict`s, where each `dict` represents the field values from `M2mfield` that you want to be in the search index.

Comment: can you please provide a code snippet